# jquery validate - add rule before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, validation, jquery-validate

The bulk of my problem is in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846925/jquery-validate-rails-4-dynamically-update-rule-after-rendering-partial-via-a

I haven't gotten any feedback for it.  I understand it might be difficult to understand.  Basically I need to change the param of a rule based on an html data attribute just before submit.  I'm wondering if there's a way to do this.

I tried adding a rule within a submitHandler :

```
$('#custom-tag').validate({
    onfocusout: false,
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      $('#custom-tag').rules("add", {
        tagUniqueness: $('#taglist').data('tag-list').split(', ')
      });
    },
    rules: {
      tag: {
        minLengthSquish: 2,
        maxLengthSquish: 25,
        alphanumericAndWhitespace: true
      }
    },
    tooltip_options: {
      tag: { placement: 'right', animation: false }
    }
  });
```

But this didnt work and I realize now the submitHandler is code to be run when a submission is valid (probably should be called validSubmissionHandler).

I am also assuming that adding a rule with the same name that already exists will overwrite the current rule and param.  If not I will just have to remove then add.

Is there a way to add a rule just before submit?

Comment: Please do not post the same question more than once.  If you did not get enough attention the first time, please [read this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make the necessary edits to your original question.

Comment: You can not put the `.rules()` method inside of the `.validate()` method.  Additionally, the `submitHandler` only fires on a valid form so this would not have worked anyway.

Comment: @Sparky I don't see this as being a duplicate.  I am trying to be concise with this question by simply asking how to add a rule immediately before submit.  I thought I wasn't getting attention with the other question because too much was going on so I am trying to break it down into more digestible parts.  Maybe I should delete the other one and just ask smaller questions like this that will eventually lead to a solution.

Comment: Yes, delete the other and I'll be able to re-open this one.

Comment: @Sparky it requires this to be re-opened before that one is deleted

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you should move your submit handler out or your validate handler.  IE, something like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
  $('#custom-tag').rules("add", {
    tagUniqueness: $('#taglist').data('tag-list').split(', ')
  });

  if ($('#custom-tag').valid() === false) {  
    // 'this' is the form, 
    event.preventDefault();
    // stop the submittion
    // ...message the user to let them know why the submit failed.
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't think you understood my question.  I want to add a rule before any type of submission.  This should not depend on if the submission was valid or not because nothing has been submitted.

Comment: Please review the code I posted again.  It does add the rule on any submission.  The call to valid() happens after the rule is added to ensure that the new rule is checked before the submission is aloud to go through.  Otherwise, you could find yourself adding the rule after the field has already been checked and your new rule would have not effect.

Comment: The plugin provides a `submitHandler` callback function precisely so you don't have to create your own.   By using a `.submit()` handler, you will likely break or bypass the validation plugin.

Comment: @sparky.  As you pointed out in a comment on the question, we would not want to add rules inside the validate function.  By using the submit event on the form, we can add the rule and trigger a manual validation without breaking validation.  The only downside is that validation code will run on this field twice, which does spin a few extra cycles but won't break anything and is unlikely to have a perceptible effect on performance.

Comment: There are better ways to do this.  Change the button to a `type="button"`, then capture its `click`, not its `submit`.  Then you can do whatever you want inside this click handler and programmatically trigger validation/submission.

Comment: Changing the button would create it's own quirks that need to be worked around (for example, the form no longer submits when the user pushes 'enter') and you'd need to prevent other methods of submission that would bypass your validation.  The submit action is the event that we're actually interested in and so is where we should attach our listener.  I've used and thoroughly tested solutions such as this in similar circumstances and it works consistently.

Comment: Shouldnt the call to .valid() be unnecessary because if it works as it should and the new added rule causes validation to fail then it should display the error message

Comment: If the validation message is setup properly, // message the user... part may be unnecessary depending on how obvious the error message is, but the field we changed the rule may have already been validated and we want to double-check that it gets validate with the new rule so it's safest to call it explicitly.

Comment: Quote:  *"Changing the button would create it's own quirks"* - nonsense.  It would allow the plugin to control the submit event and error messaging as it was designed by simply triggering the validation and initial form submission programatically.

Comment: Pressing enter no longer submits the form automically and you're still doing just as much manual work as my original answer.  
What else no longer works automatically that won't get caught until this has been in production for week?